# Given a word and a number for each letter of this word, how to create a full tree of every combinations?

Tags: python, string, list, combinations

Let's say I have the word "stack" and for each of its letters there is a number that will define the number of times the letter has to be repeated. In a JSON file I would have the following:

```
{
   "s": 4,
   "t": 3,
   "a": 2,
   "c": 5,
   "k": 2
}
```

From this I would like to generate the complete tree of every possible combinations, namely:

```
Depth 1: stack
Depth 2: stack, sstack, ssstack, sssstack
Depth 3: stack, sttack, stttack, sstack, ssttack, sstttack,ssstack, sssttack, ssstttack, sssstack, ssssttack, sssstttack
Depth 4: ... with 'a'
Depth 5: ... with 'c'
Depth 6: ... with 'k'
```

This would give 4*3*2*5*2 = 240 possibilities. Also, I have these functions from someone I asked few days ago here, and on which I modified a little bit:

```py
def all_combinations(itr):
    lst = list(itr)
    for r in range(1, len(lst) + 1): 
        for perm in itertools.combinations(lst, r=r):
            yield perm 

def all_repeats(n, letters, word):
    for rep in all_combinations(letters):
        yield ''.join(char * n if char in rep else char for char in word)
```

Which gives me:

```py
word = 'stack'
for i in range(1,5):
    liste.append(''.join(list(all_repeats(i, ['s'], word))))

Output: ['stack', 'sstack', 'ssstack', 'sssstack']
```

From this, how can I recursively call this function to create all possibilities, given the couple (letter, number) in the JSON file?

Comment: note that dictionaries are not generally considered to be "ordered" so you could easily end up with `ackst` as an answer...  saving the options in a list of lists (i.e. [['s',3],['t',3]]) would line up better with common semantics (`OrderedDict` does exist, but it's generally easier to use more appropriate data types)

Comment: @SamMason I don't know if I am answering you correctly, but I seem to have no problem to read the JSON file and even if I had duplicated entries I can manage to remove them. I thought of looping over each letter&number in the JSON file and given a list 'mylist' I would do: `mylist.append(''.join(list(all_repeats(number, letter, word))))`

Answer (score 1):

a couple of versions, first we work with a list because it's easier to index

```
options = [
   ("s", 4),
   ("t", 3),
   ("a", 2),
   ("c", 5),
   ("k", 2),
]
```

now we can get a long form version, to help understand what's going on:

```
output = ['']

for letter, repeats in options:
    tmp = []
    for num in range(repeats):
        postfix = letter * (num+1)
        for cur in output:
            tmp.append(cur + postfix)
    output = tmp
```

if you `print(output)` you'll get what you expect.  I'd suggest running in a debugger or inserting lots of `print` statements to understand what's happening

as a second version, we can shorten this all down using `itertools` as:

```
from itertools import product

tmp = [[l*(i+1) for i in range(num)] for l, num in options]
output = [''.join(l) for l in product(*tmp)]
```

you could even put it all on one line, but it becomes a little too unreadable in my opinion

a recursive solution would fit nicely as well, but I'll leave that to you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use recursion:

```
data = {'s': 4, 't': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'k': 2}
def combos(d):
  yield ''.join(map(''.join, d))
  for i in data:
     if any(c[0] == i and len(c) < data[i] for c in d):
        yield from combos([c+[i] if c[0] == i and len(c) < data[i] else c for c in d])
```